# Trace of 0x0 matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, trace

A lot of questions on the site ask what the determinant of a $0\times 0$ matrix should be. It seems to be well agreed that it should be $1$. What about the trace? I think it should be $0$ since the empty sum is $0$.

Comment: Yes, agreed . . .

Comment: What is a zero by zero matrix?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, given square matrices, $A,B$ with $$C=\begin{pmatrix}A&0\\0&B\end{pmatrix}$$

You want $\det C=\det A\det B$ and $\operatorname{tr} C= \operatorname{tr}A+ \operatorname{tr} B.$

If $A$ is $0\times 0,$ you get $C=B.$

And yes, this is the same reason you define empty products as $1$ and empty sums as $0.$

Comment: Do we reeeally want that? In any case +1 for the observation.

Comment: If $A$ is zero by zero, those zeros are not matrices with elements of zero, are they?

Comment: The $0$s are $0\times n$ and $n\times 0$ matrices, @mjw But yes, you have to saw what that means.

Comment: I’m not sure we want $0\times0$ matrices, but yeah, if we use going to use them, we want those conditions. @Yorch

Comment: Thanks!  ${}{}{}$